Why an address is sending 0,00000001 BTC to +2k vanity addresses in one transaction
I observed a strange transaction structure: one address sending
a small amount (0,00000001 BTC) to 2501 addresses. Among these
addresses there is one that receives more and replicate the pattern
(sending 0,00000001 BTC  to 2501 addresses), and so on for a few hops.
So it looks like a chain of fans. Such structures are usually used by mixers
or money laundering attemps.
Here are two chained fans
https://mempool.space/fr/address/1JGbkGeXCt3n51DjtHnEFSJJTdAh3UHfdD
However, what is surprising is that most addresses looks like vanity addresses.
1escortTNYtEH51CfZbY2FYZaCYrrNidU
1specieC2xZmvYzYPg8s16ngxZpUaLTwS
1ghetto2a7xiYaE547JMx6puK9FgSEcT3
...
Are you aware of the reason behind this strange usage of vanity addresses ?
Best,
Arnaud.

Related: https://blog.lopp.net/history-bitcoin-transaction-dust-spam-storms/
